# React Form.Check correct returns `on`. Can it return a `1` instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I've got a form that submits data to an API and from there into a MySQL database.

The form has a `Form.Check` of type `switch`. And when switched on provides the value `on`. However, I've set up my database to accept a `tinyint` -  either 1 or 0.

Is there a way to return 1 instead of `on`? For the console output below, `console.log(formData.favourite)` and `console.log(formData.scheduled)` currently return `on` or nothing at all.

### Handler

```
  const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
    title: "",
    summary: "",
    wiki_source: "",
    date: "",
    scheduled: "",
    favourite: "",
    location_id: ""
  });

  const [formData, updateFormData] = React.useState(initialFormData);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateFormData({
      ...formData,

      // Trimming any whitespace
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim()
    });
  };


const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  console.log(formData.title);
  console.log(formData.summary);
  console.log(formData.wiki_source);
  console.log(formData.date);
  console.log(formData.scheduled);
  console.log(formData.favourite);
  console.log(formData.location_id);
}
```

### Modal

```
    <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={closeModal}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>New Event</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="formTitle">
          <Form.Label>Title:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title of event" onChange={handleChange}/>
          <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            The url of the source you are adding
          </Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="formSummary">
          <Form.Label>Summary</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="summary" placeholder="Summary" onChange={handleChange}/>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="formWikiSource">
          <Form.Label>Wiki Source</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="wiki_source" placeholder="Wiki Page URL" onChange={handleChange}/>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="formDate">
          <Form.Label>Date</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control size="sm" type="date" name="date" onChange={handleChange}/>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="formScheduled">
          <Form.Check type="switch" name="scheduled" label="Set as a scheduled event" onChange={handleChange} />
        </Form.Group>


        <Form.Group controlId="formFavourite">
          <Form.Check type="switch" name="favourite" label="Set as favourite" onChange={handleChange} />
        </Form.Group>



      </Form>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: Add some processing in your backend code that inserts 1 for on and 0 for off. This isn't really a Javascript/React question.

Comment: I actually agree. The response might be how many different value should the backend be able to handle? `true` / `false`, `on`/`off` as well as `1` and `0`? I' would rather send the correct value to the server than have the server have to parse entries.

Comment: We're straying in to opinion territory here but I would argue that that's backwards. I would much rather my server code have to be able to handle multiple front ends than my client code be required know about the structure and types in my database columns. Principle of least privilege and whatnot and you have a lot more control over servers than clients even if you wrote the code for both.

Comment: Definitely opinion territory, and I would probably change my implementation to your suggestion at some point. Another question might be, what does the documentation look like? Field accepts `true`/`false`, `yes`/`no`, `on`/`off` and `1`/`0`. There's probably a blog post discussing exactly this issue. Thank you though!

Comment: No problem. I would set up a simple set of accepted 'on' states on the server, something like this (in Javascript): `const SWITCH_IS_ON = new Set(["on", 1, "1", true]);` then test for membership: `if (SWITCH_IS_ON.has(formdata.switchValue)) { console.log("on") } else { console.log("off") }`. You could translate that easily into just about any backend language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume `Form.Check` is a wrapper for an `input type="checkbox"`. If so, and assuming it supports the usual `value` property, you can use `value="1"` to make the checkbox value `"1"` (a string) rather than `"on"`. It's still a string, though you could convert it to a number, for instance:

```
updateFormData({
  ...formData,

  // Trimming any whitespace
  [e.target.name]: e.target.type === "checkbox" ? +e.target.value :  e.target.value.trim()
});
```

Or just look for `"on"` directly:

```
updateFormData({
  ...formData,

  // Trimming any whitespace
  [e.target.name]: e.target.type === "checkbox" ? (e.target.value === "on" ? 1 : 0) :  e.target.value.trim()
});
```